# How to prevent animation lag when react state changes

Tags: react-native, react-redux, state

I'm running the `CircleSnail` component from [react-native-progress](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress) as a loader while a BE operations occurs. The beginning of the animation lags and at some point it becomes smooth. It seems to be laggy while react state is being changed and once that is finished, the animation becomes smooth. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Here's my code:
`js
<CircleSnail
  direction="clockwise"
  duration={500}
  spinDuration={2000}
  color={Colors.white}
  size={27}
  indeterminate
  thickness={2}
/>`

I saved an animated gif of the 10 second spinner with the choppiness at the beginning and then getting smooth after about 1.5 second (when I suspect that the state changes have completed):

[image]